# Objective C Regex Extract Data from Line Containing Text

Tags: html, objective-c, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I'm using objective c to create a program that will pull out data from a HTML file using regexes. The only lines that are important to the program contain the text `popupName` and I need to stip all HTML tags from it as well. Can this be done with one regex?

So far I have been using `popupName` to find the line I am looking for and then deleting everything matching `<[^>]*>`.

Could these two operations be combined into one?

Here's example input:

```
            <div>
                <div class="popupName"> Bob Smith</div>
                <div class="popupTitle">
                    <i></i>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="popupTitle"></div>
                <div class="popupLink"><a href="mailto:"></a></div>
            </div>
```

From that I would like to extract only "Bob Smith". Except, I would have multiple occurrences of the line names like that.

Comment: How about showing the line code related to what you're talking about; Nobody here is a mind-reader (allegedly).

Comment: @I'L'I Do you mean like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is pretty close to what you would likely want with the addition of:

```
"popupName">(.*)|<[^>]*>
```

Adding "popupName" followed by a capture group will allow you to grab the specific info you want.

**In Objective-C:**

```
NSString* searchText = @"<div><div class=\"popupName\"> Bob Smith</div><div class=\"popupTitle\"><i></i></div><br /><div class=\"popupTitle\"></div><div class=\"popupLink\"><a href=\"mailto:\"></a></div></div><div>";
NSString *pattern = @"\"popupName\">(.*)|<[^>]*>";
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length]);

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSString *results = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:searchText options:0 range:searchRange withTemplate:@"$1"];

NSLog(@"results: %@",results);
```

**Result:**

```
results: Bob Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this for a bit, but I'm using javascript and can't do a positive lookbehind. But if your objective C can let you do a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead, you should be able to do this.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Like an example regex? It doesn't matter if it works in objective c or not.